# Raycasting Engine with multiple layers

Tags: c#, layer, monogame, raycasting

I will start with my situation right now.

I downloaded the raycast project from: https://github.com/ChrisSerpico/raycasting

This is based on the tutorial from here: https://lodev.org/cgtutor/raycasting.html

After I got the project to work, played around a bit and modified some things, I'm currently stuck with adding multiple layers (based on one map per layer). I read a lot of things around the Internet but had no luck implementing that feature.

In this project: https://github.com/Owlzy/OwlRaycastEngine

there are multiple layers added, but that is done with slices and I can't figure out how to implement this in the Serpico project (took this because the floor/ceiling drawing works a lot better there). Textures are saved like this:

```
    Texture2D canvas;  // used to convert the buffer to a single texture to be drawn
    Color[] buffer;  // screen buffer with raw color data to be drawn
    Color[][] rawData;  // raw data of the individual external textures

    // initialize graphics rendering objects
    canvas = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    buffer = new Color[SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT];

    rawData = new Color[NUM_TEXTURES][]; //number of Textures

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TEXTURES; i++)
        {
            rawData[i] = new Color[TEXTURE_WIDTH * TEXTURE_HEIGHT];
        }
```

The buffer gets filles this way in the Wallcasting loop:

```
        if (TEXTURE_WIDTH * texY + texX <= rawData[texNum].Length - 1)
        {
                buffer[SCREEN_WIDTH * y + x] = rawData[texNum][TEXTURE_WIDTH * texY + texX];
        }
        else //avoid crash when running into walls
        {
                buffer[SCREEN_WIDTH * y + x] = rawData[texNum][rawData[texNum].Length - 1];
        }
```

and finally drawn this way:

```
        canvas.SetData<Color>(buffer);
        b.Draw(canvas, new Rectangle(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT), Color.White);
```

The code is straight from the lodev tutorial. I tried around with the variables lineHeight , texY and so on but no result. The textures just get stretched, cut off or the screen gets drawn with terrible effects.

Could someone help please? I really dispair...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the call in Draw() `canvas.SetData<Color>(buffer);`

Move this line to `Update()` and it will "mostly" work.  Texture memory is shared between the CPU and GPU.  By the time Draw() is called it is expected the textures already exist in GPU memory.  Transferring data during draws causes random tearing.

The mostly comes in the nondeterministic delays between Update() and Draw() and the PCIE memory transfer.